# Flutter: Type 'MyHomePage' is not a subtype of type 'Container' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, riverpod

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

I was using my _page() function to create my homepage, but now that I have created a new file for MyHomePage, it is giving me that type error. If I remove that "as Container" part of my context.read line, I get a different error.

I am a bit confused on the "as Container" part anyway, but I think it has to do with flutter 2.0, as it wasn't there until after I migrated to 2.0.

When looking into this error, I saw that I should try to restart the application, so I did that and it seemed to work, until I switch to a different page, and then try switching back to the home page, which is when I get the error.

I am not sure if this is important for this error, but I am using Riverpod for my state management.

my_drawer.dart:

```
class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {     
  MyDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);     

  @override     
  _MyDrawerState createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {      
  Widget _homePage = MyHomePage();         
  Widget _galleryPage = _page(Colors.white, "Gallery");        
  Widget _bookAppPage = _page(Colors.white, "Book An Appointment");        
  Widget _aboutUsPage = _page(Colors.white, "About Us");        
  Widget _contactUsPage = _page(Colors.white, "Contact Us");      
  Widget _settingsPage = _page(Colors.white, "Settings");

  @override     
  void initState() {     
    super.initState();     
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {      
      context.read(fragmentProvider).state = _homePage as Container;     
    });    
  } 

...
...
...

// Temp function to create the rest of the pages
_page(Color color, String title) {
  return Container(
    height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity,
    color: color,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        '$title',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is MyHomePage class:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {       
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);      

  @override      
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();       
}      

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {            
  @override      
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {       
    return Scaffold(       
      appBar: MyAppBar(),      
      drawer: MyDrawer(),      
      body: Stack(       
        children: [       
          Text("Home"),       
          Consumer(       
            builder: (context, watch, _) {      
              final body = watch(fragmentProvider).state;       
              return body;     
            },    
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider creating an enum for each page, then changing your fragment provider to provide that enum, then using a map to decide which page to display based on the enum, instead of storing widgets in a provider. I don't think what you're doing is wrong, but it is strange.

Comment: I will look into that, but I am still fairly new to Flutter and honestly have no idea how to do that. If you find any links that could help me out, please send it!

Comment: I would honestly say you are overcomplicating things and would highly recommend looking at the official and third party examples here before moving on: https://riverpod.dev/docs

Comment: I will read over the docs and try to get a better understanding of how to use Riverpod, as this is the first project I have used Riverpod in. I looked into enums and maps yesterday, but I am still unsure how to properly use it. Hopefully I will end up figuring it out. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. By the way, the link you provided did not work, but I assume you meant this link: [link](riverpod.dev/docs/getting_started)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactored my code in order to get the result that I was looking for. Instead of using Riverpod and trying to use state management to switch between pages, I opted for the built in `Navigator` and `MaterialPageRoute` widgets to navigate between pages in my drawer.

I replaced this code for each `context.read()` line.

```
Navigator.push(context, 
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MyHomePage()));
```

I removed the Consumer widget as well as all of the `Widget _...Page = ...;` lines. I also got rid of my `_page()` function and just went ahead and created basic pages for each page and then imported them into my_drawer.dart.

As Alex Hartford was saying in the comments, I was just over complicating everything by trying to use Riverpod to switch between each page.

After making these changes, the app behaves exactly as I need it to. Thanks to everyone who replied and helped me out. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast `_homePage` as a `Container`, but `_homePage` is an instance of `MyHomePage` which is a `StatefulWidget`. All your other pages are actually wrapped in `Container`, so those casts will succeed.

I'm not sure what the type of `context.read(fragmentProvider).state` is, so it's hard to say what's the actual fix here without more information.

Comment: I had attempted to make it "as Scaffold" because that is what MyHomePageState is returning in the build method. However, that wasn't working. I had not thought to try "as Widget" until someone else replied to this post, but that wasn't working either. Is there any other part of the code that I could show you that could help with finding what the type of context.read(fragmentProvider).state is? my fragmentProvider looks like this, ''' final fragmentProvider = StateProvider((ref) => Container()); '''

Answer (score 1):

> From this code:

```
  context.read(fragmentProvider).state = _homePage as Container;
```

> Replace the Container with Widget:

```
  context.read(fragmentProvider).state = _homePage as Widget;
```

Comment: changing it to "as Widget" causes the application to not compile. This is the error I recieved. "Error: A value of type 'Widget' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Container'"

Comment: Then in your fragmentProvider replace every Container with Widget

Comment: It was giving me an error when I did that as well, but I actually just got it working without using Riverpod. I just used Navigator and MaterialPageRoute and it worked. Thanks for the help though!